# locahost returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on React component edit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, parcel

I use `MEAN` stack, `nodemon` and `Parcel`. Every time when I edit my **frontend** code, `axios` returns `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, and I need to reload page 1-3 times to avoid this error. What can cause it?

Here is my request code:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')
      .then((res) => {
        let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        newState.taskList = res.data;
        this.setState(newState);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Could it be that your backend is running via `nodemon` or similar? And changing something in the frontend code also triggers a restart of the backend?

Answer (score 0):

You may test your call with tool like postman, the error can provide from your server, you can also get more information with catch the error like

```
 Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')
  .then((res) => {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    newState.taskList = res.data;
    this.setState(newState);
  })
  .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: Insomnia doesn't return error. Also I said that after some reloadings everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Compare baseURL (http://localhost:5000/) port (5000) and the port on which server is running, those should be same.

Answer (score 0):

baseURL(http://localhost:5000/) port (5000) and the port your server is running should be the same. I got the same type of error on my react app while trying to get data from a local folder that has db.json file in it -  http://localhost:8000/blogs because my server port was 3000(locahost:3000).

Then I ran this command on a new terminal to watch the json file  `npx json-server --watch data/db.json --port 8000` then it worked perfectly!